# Is there a way to download graph.py and its class LinkedDirectedGraph or the abstractcollection.py and its class AbstractCollection?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010

I have the following code below and when I run the code on visual studio, it says "no module named abstractcollection".  So I tried downloading the package on visual studio by going to the python environment and searching for it. It is not able to find either 'abstractcollection' or 'graph' but does find other modules like matplotlib. I've provided a picture of the visual studio window layout incase this may help.

```
from abstractcollection import AbstractCollection
class LinkedDirectedGraph(AbstractCollection):
    def __init__(self, sourceCollection = None):
        self.edgeCount = 0
        self.vertices = dict() # Dictionary of vertices
        AbstractCollection.__init__(self, sourceCollection)
    def addVertex(self, label):
        """Adds a vertex with the given label to the graph."""
        self.vertices[label] = LinkedVertex(label)
        self.size += 1
    def addEdge(self, fromLabel, toLabel, weight):
        """Connects the vertices with an edge with the given weight."""
        fromVertex = self.getVertex(fromLabel)
        toVertex = self.getVertex(toLabel)
        fromVertex.addEdgeTo(toVertex, weight)
        self.edgeCount += 1


g = LinkedDirectedGraph()
# Insert vertices
g.addVertex("A")
g.addVertex("B")
g.addVertex("C")
g.addVertex("D")
g.addVertex("E")
# Insert weighted edges
g.addEdge("A", "B", 3)
g.addEdge("A", "C", 2)
g.addEdge("B", "D", 1)
g.addEdge("C", "D", 1)
g.addEdge("D", "E", 2)
print(g)
```

[Click Here for visual studio layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWLDx.jpg)

Error Message:

3'Exception Thrown: No module named 'abstractcollection' 3'

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete error report starting with the word **traceback**. You can surround the report with 3` before and 3` after to properly format the output.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I went ahead and made an edit. Placed the exact 'error message' I am seeing.

Comment: Have you installed the abstractcollections library into your selected python environment?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a package called `abstractcollection`. I searched on [PyPi](https://pypi.org), the Python Package Index, which is the standard place to publish Python packages. There are a couple of references:

- [zope.schema](https://pypi.org/project/zope.schema/) - Provides `zope.schema._field.AbstractCollection`, renamed to `Collection` in 4.6.0 in 2018.
- [plone.dexterity](https://pypi.org/project/plone.dexterity/) - Mentions `AbstractCollection` in the 2011 notes.

Your code does not look like you are working with [Plone](https://plone.org/), a Content Management System, or [Zope](https://zope.dev/), the web application framework, so I doubt you are looking for these.

You may be familiar with Java code, which has a class [AbstractCollection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html), which makes it easier to implement the `Collection` interface.

The closest thing in Python might be [collections.UserList](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=dict#collections.UserDict), which wraps a `list` object and allows you to override the standard `list` behaviors. I have not needed this in my Python experience, and I doubt you do either.

I suspect you don't need a base class at all. Something like this may work:

```py
class LinkedDirectedGraph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.edgeCount = 0
        self.vertices = {} # Dictionary of vertices
```

You'll still need to define the `LinkedVertex` and some other methods. Hopefully this gets you unstuck.